How can we account for the change in heat capacity of gas with temperature and pressure when doing energy balance?
Consider the following scenario.
There is a gas in container $A$ with the following properties:

Mass $m_1 = 100 \ \text{kg}$
Specific heat $c_{p, 1} = 1 \ \dfrac{\text{kJ}}{\text{kg K}}$
Temperature $T_1 = 30 \ ^\circ \text{C} \ .$

There is gas of same composition at higher pressure in container $B$:

Mass $m_2 = 10 \ \text{kg}$
Specific heat $c_{p, 2} = 2 \ \dfrac{\text{kJ}}{\text{kg K}}$
Temperature $T_2 = 120 \ ^\circ \text{C} \ .$

The containers are joined and gases mixed. What is the resulting temperature $T$ of the mixture?
One way to do energy balance is as follows:
$$m_1 \ c_{p,1} \ T_1 + m_2 \ c_{p,2} \ T_2 = (m_1 \ c_{p,1} + m_2 \ c_{p,2}) \ T \ .$$
However, I am confused by the term on the right side of the equation.
The specific heat of gas changes with pressure and temperature. Both these things will change when the gases in the two containers are mixed.
So is the energy balance equation correct? Or does it necessitate an assumption, which seems wrong to me, that $c_p$ value is constant?
Please let me know in case I am missing something. Thanks in advance!

It is correct for an ideal gas if the Cp's are replaced by Cv's and the tanks are not insulated from one another, and the heat capacities are constant with temperature.

The molar specific heat of a gas is constant for an ideal gas: $c_p=(\frac{f}2 +1)R$.  Perhaps you're dealing with a gas that's far from idealness, though?
